# Need assistance regex matching a single quote, but do not include the quote in the result

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find out a way to match the following test string:

```
token = '1866FB352F4DF76BCB92C3482DB7D7B4F562';
```

The data I want returned is...

```
1866FB352F4DF76BCB92C3482DB7D7B4F562
```

I've tried the following, the closes I have is this, but it's including the single quote at the end:

```
(?!token = ')(\w+)';
```

Now, another one, which works closely, but it's including the last single quote:

```
'([^']+)'
```

Anyone want to take a stab at this?

Update: After looking at what I need to parse, I found the same value in the html, in the form area, which looks like it might be easier to grab:

```
name="token" value="482CD1FE037F68D5A36F4C961A6D57D9"
```

Again, I just need the contents within value="*"

However, the regex will have to parse the entire html source, so I assume I will need to search for name="toke" value= but not include that in the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regex engine supports [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can use

```
(?<=')\w+(?=')
```

This matches an alphanumeric word if it's surrounded by single quotes, without making those quotes a part of the actual match. If you only want to match hexadecimal numbers, use

```
(?i)(?<=')[0-9A-F]+(?=')
```

**EDIT:**

Since you have now added that you're using JMeter, and because JMeter doesn't support lookbehind assertions for reasons incomprehensible to me (because Java itself does support it just fine), you can possibly cheat like this:

```
\b[0-9A-F]+(?=')
```

only checks whether an entire hex number occurs right before a `'` character. It does not check for the presence of an opening quote, but chances are that this won't matter.

Comment: Thank you, seeing if JMeter supports lookaround in the regex tester

Comment: Note that `(?<=regexp)` (lookbehind) is not supported in JMeter

Comment: @stackoverflow: Interesting, I wonder why JMeter isn't using Java's regex library.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, really appreciate it!